# What is *.dll.embed.manifest and *.dll.intermediate.manifest?

Tags: c++, dll

I have created a class as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

#define  DLLEXPORT _declspec( dllexport )

using namespace std;

class DLLEXPORT xyz
{
public:
    void printclass();
};
```

And my aim is to export the class xyz to a dll.

here is the .cxx file for the same.

```
#include "xyz.h"

void xyz::printclass()
{
    cout<<"hello";
}
```

the project is building fine but there is no *.dll in the debug folder. instead there is *.dll.embed.manifest and *.dll.intermediate.manifest .  I want to know what are these *.manifest files. And how could I get *.dll for my project.

I have created this project in visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look in the solution directory, not your project directory.

A solution can have multiple projects, each having their own debug and release folder. Each project writes its final files to the solution's debug and release directory, which is the directory that contains the project folders.

Assuming the solution's name is also XYZ, 
  Look in `"Documents\Visual Studio\Projects\XYZ\Debug"`

Comment: Yeah I found the dlls in the debug folder for solution, great thanks, but what are these manifest files.

Comment: The manifest files store information regarding the dependencies the DLL or executable files rely on. They are in XML format and the final manifest is embedded in the DLL (or .exe) by default. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375365(v=vs.85).aspx)